# What does it mean when a charger has 5V 0.7A?

Tags: power-supply, usb, wall-wart

For my phone (Samsung Galaxy Note 2) I have several chargers. I noticed that with some of them it takes much longer to charge the phone, to the point that a whole night is not enough to charge it. So I did some measuring.

```
Lab power supply   421 mA   4.8 V
Charger 1           92 mA   4.7 V
Charger 2          152 mA   4.7 V
Charger 3          421 mA   4.8 V
```

From these figures I guess the phone needs at least 4.7 V to charge and it regulates the current intake accordingly.

All three chargers look identical and are marked [image: 5.0V = 0.7A] (click for full view).

Do I have faulty chargers or does `5.0V 0.7A` actually mean "can output 700 mA with whatever voltage drop is necessary"?

Comment: You measured these values while you were charging the phone, right?

Comment: apparently it the markings on the outside don't mean a whole lot!

Comment: How are you measuring these? Cut up usb cable?

Comment: Yes. Like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/h6LBv.png

Answer (score 2):

A power supply specifying 5.0 V and 0.7 A output means that the voltage across its output should be 5.0 V while any current between 0 A and 0.7 A is drawn by the load on its output.

Your measurements would indicate that none of your power supplies are meeting that specification exactly; but there are two effects you must consider:

- Tolerance. No voltage regulation can be perfect, and there is no reason for a typical power supply to be that precise. USB 2.0 specifies a supply voltage of 5.00 ± 0.25 volts, so a minimum of 4.75 volts.
- Voltage drop due to the resistance of the cable attached to the power supply. (I assume the figure for your lab power supply came from the meter of the power supply itself, thus showing approximately no drop.) This results in a low reading (and a lower voltage supplied to the device) as more current is drawn. It is possible for the power supply to compensate for a known cable resistance, but this is not usually done.

So, your measurements (assuming they were made correctly) are quite consistent with the phone refusing to charge (or charging at a low rate) due to the input voltage being below 4.75 volts. The power supplies might meet their specification in their internal circuit, but if so, the permanently attached cable contains conductors which are too thin, and so the whole must be considered out of specification.

(Note, however, that there is no obligation on the phone manufacturer to set a limit of exactly 4.75 volts. In fact, unless you connected the proper resistors to the data lines when you tested using your lab power supply, we can see that the phone does *not* follow USB specifications for allowable current draw. This is quite common.)

Comment: it's possible to compensate for the drop by using feedback or measuring the current and predicting the drop.

Comment: @Jasen Thank you; I can see that measuring the current would be sufficient and so I have removed the incorrect statement.

Comment: just to add another effect: certain phones would current limit their charger circuit if input voltage to it drops below some set margin, USB low limit typically. This explains the 92 ma output of charger 1; if you load it with a dummy load instead of a phone you'll get different figure.

Comment: Indeed I was using the meter of the power supply, I corrected the value for "Lab power supply".

Comment: @OlegMazurov Yes, that seems to be what my phone does. When I give it less voltage, it switches to a lower charge current (in approximately 100mA steps) and stays there.